# Android - java adding please wait message

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My question is how can i add a message "Loading please wait " . Until the request is made and response is parsed to table.

Is there approach to that using this method ?

Like this when i run this i don't know if there is no data on response or response is not yet received.

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, apiURL,
        new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("sales");

                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(  MainActivity.this   );
                        TextView t1v = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                        t1v.setText(employee.getString("saletype"));
                        t1v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        stk.addView(tbrow);

                        // .......

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }
) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        params.put("store", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        return params;
    }
};

mQueue.add(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show Progress bar on adding request object in queue.

```
mQueue.add(postrequest); 

progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...Please Wait"); 
progressDialog.show();
```

Then Dismiss it on receiving response.

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);

     JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("sales");

     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

      TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
      TextView t1v = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

      t1v.setText(employee.getString("saletype"));
      t1v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      stk.addView(tbrow);

      // ....... 

     }

    progressDialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Also,

```
 @Override 
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { 
          progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `dismiss()` in the `onErrorResponse()` method. Also, please format your code...it is a bit difficult to read.

Comment: @Barns Since i'm beginner on android development why you think i can improve my code / format ? . This is the way android studio format it automatically

Comment: You misunderstood. I meant the format of the code in your post. You had too many spaces in the lines of code after the `try{` block... But you fixed it with your last edit. I was just pointing that out. It wasn't too bad. But now it looks much better.